# open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, android

I've tried getting OutputStream or createNewFile if MyCurrent file was not exists, but I have an exception " open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) ". when I check fileManager in my android device, I see MyCurrent file created with 0 bytes size. I'm sure that directory is exists. What's wrong in my Code? Thanks.

```
  final File fileBackupDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/Pioneers Source/" + "/DownLoad/temp.apk");
  if (!fileBackupDir.exists()) 
  {
   try {                                        
        fileBackupDir.createNewFile();
        OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileBackupDir));

        } catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
   }
```

Comment: already add the permission on manifest?

Comment: ... `/" + "/` .... = ?

Comment: Yes, Use this Manifest     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: What's the reason for a `string concatenation`, here? **String concatenations should be avoided whenever possible**, for performance (because they are freaking **S L O W**)

Answer (score 0):

> You have a double / at "Pioneers Source **//** DownLoad"

**replace**

```
 final File fileBackupDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/Pioneers Source/" + "/DownLoad/temp.apk");
```

**to**

```
 final File fileBackupDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/Pioneers Source/" + "DownLoad/temp.apk");
```

Comment: I tried it with final File fileBackupDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/Pioneers Source /DownLoad/temp.apk");  , but do not work

Comment: Do you have those folders? If not you need to create those too